# For any positive integer, there exists a positive integer where their product is a perfect square?

Tags: solution-verification, proof-explanation, integers, square-numbers

***Prove or disprove that for any positive integer $m$
there is a positive integer $n$ such that $mn + 1$ is a perfect square.***

My reasoning:
We're asked to show that $mn + 1 = p^2$ and that given any positive integer $m$ we can find positive integer $n$ where this holds.

Rewriting, we get
$$mn = p^2 - 1 = (p - 1)(p + 1)$$

**Case #1**

Let $m = p - 1$ and $n = p + 1$. For a given $m$ we just take
$$n = p + 1 = (p - 1) + 2 = m + 2$$

Note also that since $m > 0$, here we have $n > 0$.

**Case #2**

Let $m = p + 1$ and $n = p - 1$. Given some value $m$, we should
choose $n$ like
$$n = p - 1 = (p + 1) - 2 = m - 2$$

Now, this is fine for $m > 2$ but for $m \in \{1,2\}$ we have that the corresponding $n$ is $n \leq 0$. This goes against our requirement that $n > 0$.

Is there an error in this reasoning? To me, looking only at **Case #1** seems like a loss of generality.

Comment: Take $n=m+2$. Then $mn+1=(m+1)^2$ is a perfect square. And take $n=m^2+3m+3$, then $mn+1=(m+1)^3$ is a perfect cube. This is  well known.

Comment: You are overcomplicating it. Case #1 basically means it's enough to choose $n=m+2$.

Comment: The statement of the claim that you're trying to prove is confusing, especially regarding the quantifiers. Here's how it should read: *Give a positive integer $m$, there exist positive integers $n$ and $p$ such that $mn + 1 = p^2$.* Once it's written clearly, the task makes more sense: Explicitly determine $n$ and $p$ in terms of the given number $m$.